# Win CMD, move file to a directory depending on the file date

Tags: date, batch-file, copy, cmd

I am trying to write a Windows 7 batch script that moves the pics of my camera on a SD card to a directory on the HDD of my computer. This directory should contain the year and the month of the creation date of the pic.

Example file: `E:\DCIM\100CANON\IMG_0190.jpg, 2012/12/31`

To: `C:\Users..Pictures\2012\12\`

My idea was writing FOR loops for the year, month and day and then moving the files which are newer then the resulting date:

```
FOR /L %%Y IN (2014,-1,2011) DO ( FOR /L %%M IN (12,-1,1) DO ( FOR /L %%D IN (31,-1,1) DO ( ROBOCOPY E:\DCIM\100CANON\ C:\Users..Pictures\%%Y\%%M\ *.* /MAXAGE:%%Y%%M%%D /MOVE ) ) )
```

But that does not work becaues of the missing 0 in the months and days below 10...

Unfortunately, I have not got a good knowledge in Windows batch files coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are separating them by month, you will not need the day loop.

All I did was remove the day loop (excluding pictures older than the first day of each month) and added the if statements which will call the `robocopy` command with a padded month digit.

```
FOR /L %%Y IN (2014,-1,2011) DO (
    FOR /L %%M IN (12,-1,1) DO (
        if %%M LSS 10 ROBOCOPY E:\DCIM\100CANON\ C:\Users..Pictures\%%Y\0%%M\ *.* /MAXAGE:%%Y0%%M01 /MOVE /L
        if %%M GEQ 10 ROBOCOPY E:\DCIM\100CANON\ C:\Users..Pictures\%%Y\%%M\ *.* /MAXAGE:%%Y%%M01 /MOVE /L
    )
)
```

I would also recommend using the `/L` option on robocopy to verify the results before actually moving the files!  Just remove the `/L` when you are ready to actually move the files and not just display the files.

See [`robocopy /?`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for help.